# Map JSON array to List using RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm having trouble mapping the `environments` array in the below JSON response output into a list of `Environment` objects using `RestTemplate`.

The `name` property of ApplicationData is being populated with `Deploy app` which is correct. However, the list of environments in Application Data is `null`.  I'd like it to be populated with the corresponding id's and names from the output.

***JSON output***

```
{
    "id": 4587521,
    "oid": 8738390651982315522,
    "name": "Deploy app",
    "description": "",
    "environments": [
        {
            "id": 4751361,
            "name": "Stage",
            "position": 0,
            "configurationState": "TASKED"
        },
        {
            "id": 4751362,
            "name": "Dev",
            "position": 1,
            "configurationState": "TASKED"
        },
    ]
}
```

***ApplicationData.java***

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ApplicationData {

  private String name;
  private List<Environment> environments;

  // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

***Environment.java***

```
public class Environment {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

***RestTemplate code***

```
List<ApplicationData> applications = new ArrayList<>();

ResponseEntity<List<ApplicationData>> response =
  restTemplate.exchange("/deploy/project/all", HttpMethod.GET, null, 
  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ApplicationData>>() {});

applications = response.getBody();
```

Comment: There is an extrea camma in your environments json. I'm not really sure but try to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to Environnement and be careful to respect standard naming rule according to getters. Your code seems to be good.

Comment: That was simply a typo in JSON output on my part

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying my ApplicationData class so the property was an array of Environment objects:

`private Environment[] environments;`

It then populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

But what I do not get is, you serialize to `List<ApplicationData>` but your JSON output snippet shows only a single ApplicationData object, not a list with this single object. Did you apply any [Jackson Deserialization Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features)  like `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`?